# Publishing my WebApi changes the config from a .exe to a .dll removing the block on Swagger

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-3.1, swashbuckle

Swagger has been added to the WebApi. In order to avoid Swagger being available in Production there's a check in the Startup.cs. This is working fine when you change the deployed reference from .dll to .exe. However when leaving it at .dll, Swagger remains available. Why is the config being changed and how can this be prevented?

Publish profile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>False</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <LastUsedPlatform>.NET</LastUsedPlatform>
    <WDPMergeOption>MergeAllOutputsToASingleAssembly</WDPMergeOption>
    <UseMerge>True</UseMerge>
    <SingleAssemblyName>WebApi.Published</SingleAssemblyName>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <ProjectGuid>2603565c-93cb-4c9f-bae2-86889931c11e</ProjectGuid>
    <publishUrl>..\..\Publish\WebApi\Release</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <EnvironmentName>Production</EnvironmentName>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Config in source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\WebApi.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="443" />
          <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Published config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\WebApi.dll" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="443" />
          <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you also add code of `Startup.cs` where you enable & disable swagger?

Comment: ASP.NET Core doesn't use `.config` files. What you posted is the file used by *IIS* to configure in-process hosting, nothing more

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the published `.config` file. The application binary is a `.dll` and the `aspNetCore processPath=".\WebApi.dll"` tag uses that dll

Answer (score -1):

I ended up copying the proper web.config in a post-build event:

```
  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="copy &quot;$(ProjectDir)Web.$(ConfigurationName).Config&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)Web.Config&quot; />
  </Target>
```

Because of:

```
<IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>True</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
```

The Web.Config isn't automatically copied with the publish. But this command is needed to avoid changing the .exe to a .dll. So in addition a command is added so the publish also copies over the Web.Config:

```
  <Target Name="CopyWebConfig" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetDir)\Web.Config" DestinationFiles="$(PublishDir)\Web.Config"/>
  </Target>
```

Comment: Why are you using a web.config in the first place? ASP.NET Core doesn't use `config` files. The `web.config` that gets published is *only* used to configure in-process hosting in IIS. Configuration for  the web application itself goes into `Startup.cs`, the `applicationsettings.json` files and any other config source you defined in `Startup`

Comment: Which means that what you posted here doesn't fix the problem. On the contrary, it *causes problems*. Without that `dll` IIS won't be able to host the application. If you copy the *development* configuration, you'll end up with a `DEVELOPMENT` environment

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos And what's included in the config? IIS hosting stuff only. Yes, that's what it's for. Yes I also have appsettings.json for user configuration. I also have separate Web.Config and publish profiles for debug and release, that wasn't the problem. The application is running fine in IIS with this configuration.

Comment: Then why did you post a question here? The two configs you posted are the same. The change from `.exe` to `.dll` didn't change anything. That `.exe` wasn't the actual application (unless you used single-file publishing), it was a bootstrapper that called the `.dll`